# Sort questions by their answers' votes

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, votes, sorting

When looking through questions for ones that still don't have well done answers, I think a good way to sort the questions is by total *answer* score, the theory being that once a question has been adequately dealt with, it's answers will generally have higher scores. Can we implement this feature somehow?

Comment: I suppose you know already that you can find all questions with no answers of positive score on [the Unanswered tab](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

Comment: @msh210 Yes. I was wondering how to find the questions with eg. 8 votes that have one answer with a 2 and one with a 1. Likely that question could use a better answer (not for sure, just likely).

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=

Comment: @msh210 Thanks I didn't know about most of those Super Ninja options. But the one I'm looking for still isn't there.